# Parsing JSON response from request GET call asynchronously

Tags: json, http, rust

I am making a GET call to some API which in turn would return me `list` of JSON objects. However, I couldn't parse this into list of custom data structure.

Closest I could come to

```
struct Pokemon {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    height: i32,
    weight: i32,
}

let mut response = client.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/111")
    .send()
    .expect("Failed to send request");
if let Ok(pokemon) = response.json::<Pokemon>() {
    println!("{:#?}", pokemon);
}
```

Could anyone please provide me suitable example for same. Also, is this the standard way of doing it. I mean what difference would it make to use something like

```
let url = url.parse().expect("API URL parsing bug");
let request = Request::new(reqwest::Method::GET, url);

self.inner
    .execute(request)
    .map_err(Error::Request)
    .and_then(move |response: Response| {
        ...
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Response::json`, you must implement `serde::Deserialize` for `Pokemon`. You can do this by adding the following to your Cargo.toml, under `[dependencies]`.

```
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

Then, add `use serde::Deserialize;` at the top of your file, and change the declaration of `Pokemon` to:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Pokemon {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    height: i32,
    weight: i32,
}
```